# Updating React state after Finished Rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, state

I'm learning about react's lifecycle methods and I'm wondering how to best address this scenario:

I have a component that fetches information about someone's hobbies

```
  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.fetchHobbies(this.props.params.id);
  }
```

The data is sent to a reducer which is mapped as a prop at bottom of the component

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return { 
    hobbies:state.hobbies.user
  };
}
```

I have a component called twitterbootstrap which relies on my component's state to see what rows are selected.

```
const selectRowProp = {
  mode: 'radio',
  clickToSelect: true,
  bgColor: "rgba(139, 195, 74, 0.71)",
  selected: this.state.selected,
};
```

Here's my question. I want to access `this.props.hobbies.selected`.

--UPDATE I'm using componentWillRecieveProps as it has a setState option.

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
    this.setState({selected:next.props.hobbies })
}
```

I want to use this.props.hobbies.selected as the next prop to be recieved. How would I incorporate that?

Comment: Could you use componentWillReceiveProps ?

Comment: @ioseph thanks for the tip! I did a bit of research and I think this is on the right track. Do you know what the proper syntax for setting the state "selected" to this.props.hobbies.selected is?

Comment: selected: nextProps.hobbies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

nextProps is the props object that is passed after the first rendering. there is nothing called next.props in the function componentWillReceiveProps. you can do something like that.

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
    this.setState({selected:nextProps.hobbies })
}
```